# How to upload a SVG file to google drive to be converted to native drawing format and editable in google docs?

Tags: google-drive-api

How to programatically upload a SVG file (or any other public vector based format) to Google Drive to be stored/converted there to google drawing native format? So the uploaded file can be later open and edited directly in the google drive environment.
Is it possible?
When I upload a SVG file to Google Drive using web based UI, the SVG file is stored, but not converted and cannot be edited. It can be just viewed.

Comment: try converting the SVG file to WMF by any drawing tool(eg. Inkscape). [Import WMF files into Google drawings - Docs Blog](http://googledocs.blogspot.jp/2010/12/import-wmf-files-into-google-drawings.html)

Comment: @wolfan Link now broken. Uploading .wmf to Google Drive and opening it now automatically works with drawings.  But I could not copy the drawing into a google doc document.

Answer (score 2):

you can upload your SVG file to http://openclipart.org and then there is a button for WMF / EMF that allows you to download and use your file in Google Drawings, Libreoffice, and Microsoft Office.

Comment: but why WMF exported file in google drawing not allowing to edit already written Text-box ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the `convert` parameter to `true` when uploading the file?

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#optional-parameters